# Complex iterators in C

Tags: c, iterator, c99

note: [this was originally asked on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30840112/complex-iterators-in-c).

Part of my current project involves iterating over sequences that don't necessarily exist. For example, I have something similar to a relational database in memory, so say I have three arrays

```
typedef struct { size_t car_index, size_t part_index } car_part_t;

car_ * cars;
part_t * parts;
car_part * car_parts;
```

I want to be able to iterate over all the parts in a given car, for example. I specifically want the `part` and not the `car_part`. My current solution is

```
typedef struct {
    size_t car_index;
    size_t part_index;
    size_t m_car_part_index; // keeps progress
} car_part_iterator_t;
```

and to have two functions

```
car_part_iterator_t car_part_first(size_t car_index);
```

which returns an iterator set up such that `it.part_index` is the index of the part in `parts`, `it.car_index` is the car selected by the first parameter, and `it.m_car_part_index` is a 'private' variable used to track progress in the `car_parts` list.

I then have a similar function for getting the next one

```
bool car_part_next(car_part_iterator_t * it);
```

which moves to the next car part, and returns if the iterator is still valid. Finally for completeness I have

```
bool car_part_valid(car_part_iterator it);
```

to check if the current iterator is still valid. So it can be used in a for loop like

```
for (car_part_iterator_t it = car_part_first(car_index);
    car_part_valid(it); car_part_next(&it))
{
    // use it.part_index ...
}
```

To me, this sounds like a good solution that I came to after some trial and error. I also experimented with a function that returns an iterator before the first result, so the next` function would return the first result, for use in while loops.

Is this a good pattern? I assume a known one. Does it have a name? Are there pitfalls I'm not seeing?

---

notes:

On SO the generality of this was questioned (ie it can be made more general), but as it stands I'm not too bothered about that.

It was also pointed out that the `valid` function isn't strictly needed for the loop, but it allows for a more natural `for` loop, and is also sometimes useful outside of loops.

Comment: The first/next structure immediately makes me think of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAR_and_CDR -- I don't know if that has a particular name, though.

Comment: Looks to me like you're begging to upgrade to C++...

Answer (score 3):

> Is this a good pattern?

Yes, in general.

I can't see how it interacts with your data in detail, but it works well in lots of places, and is probably fine here too.

> I assume a known one. Does it have a name?

It's just the [iterator pattern](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?IteratorPattern). It may be more complex than a linked-list or array iterator, but it's not so obviously different to a tree iterator.

> Are there pitfalls I'm not seeing?

Well, your current implementation seems to depend on global state. Generalizing this aspect is probably a good idea.

---

Lastly, when you said the sequence might not exist, I was expecting to see an iterator lazily generating the values. Since that isn't the case here, what do you actually mean?

Answer (score 2):

Yes.. This is good pattern, but you can do something like this:

```
typedef struct {
   part_t *i, *end;
} car_part_iterator_t;
```

Then have functions

```
car_part_iterator_t car_part_iterator_first(size_t car_index);
void car_part_next(car_part_iterator* iter); // because I don't know why you need bool there
bool car_part_valid(car_part_iterator iter);
```

After that you can use it like this:

```
for(car_part_iterator_it it = car_part_iterator_first(index);
    car_part_valid(it); car_part_next(&it)) {
   doSomething(*(it.i));
}
```

And you can actually iterate like this if you want:

```
for(part_t *it = car_part_iterator_first(index); it != car_part_iterator_end(index); it++) {
   // do something..
}
```

Then you don't have to create another iterator struct, but still have to create to functions, though you can omit those functions if you want..

**Edit:** Because this website is not allowing me to comment, I have to embed my reply here. I think the *end in car_part_iterator_t struct is supposed to just check that. We set that *end to point to the part after current car's last part. In C, we can iterate over arrays like this:

```
int *array = calloc(sizeof(int), 10);
// we want to iterate over the first 5 elements
int *first = array;
int *end   = array + 5; // the element after the 5th element
for(int *it = first; it != end; it++)
    printf("Hello, %d\n", *it);
free(array);
```

Comment: Problem is that the iterator you've posted doesn't contain the information needed to find the next element. Given a `part_t`, the next part could (and likely is) part of a different car, or many cars, since it's a many-to-many relationship.